# update user preference set record type preferences programatically

Tags: record-type, user

In order to avoid selecting RecordType splash screen while creating a record, salesforce allows the user to set the preference to choose an option to default to default record type.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=user_recordtype.htm&type=5

Is there a way to set this programatically ? I believe this can be done by overriding quickaction button. But I am not able to overide "new event" on calendar.

Issue I am trying to solve.
User clicks "new event" from Calendar, splash screen prompts user to select record type. I am not able to override the "New Button"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing the administrator can do is to set only one active record type for the user. This would bypass the record type selection screen automatically. There's no way to access Personal Preferences via an API.

Comment: ok  thats what I thought. thank you!